# Uploaded file format changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I'm using telerik controls to upload a photo and store it in a folder in my project.

[image: Solution Explorer]

I wrote the code to upload the image and store it in the 'images' folder
It works, but it changed the format of the uploaded file. Instead of putting in images, it puts the png/jpg photo as a Telerik.Web.UI.AsyncUploadedFile

Here is my aspx page

```
    <asp:Label ID="PhotoLabel" runat="server" Text="Upload a photo"></asp:Label>
    <telerik:RadAsyncUpload RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ManualUpload="false"  ID="AsyncUpload1" MultipleFileSelection="Disabled" OnFileUploaded="AsyncUpload1_FileUploaded"></telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
    <telerik:RadButton runat="server" Text="Sibmit new photos" OnClick="UploadFiles_Click"></telerik:RadButton>
    <asp:Label ID="error" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

And my code behind

```
protected void UploadFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if(AsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (UploadedFile file in AsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles)
            {
                string targetFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images");
                string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, file.ToString());

                file.SaveAs(targetPath);    
            }
            error.Text = "File Uploaded";
            error.Visible = true;

        }
        else
        {
            error.Text = "no files to upload";
            error.Visible = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        error.Text = ex.ToString();
        error.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

EDIT : Okay so I figured out what my issue was and how I can fix it. I changed one line of code

```
string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, file.GetName());
```

And it worked. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, file.ToString());
```

to

```
string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, file.GetName());
```

Solved my issues.